# PHP glob pattern issue

Tags: php, glob

I am trying to get certain files in my directory by using glob.

My pattern is like

```
foreach(glob($root . "../test/te[0-9]{2}.xml") as $filename){
  echo $filename;
}
```

The files are

```
0051_001.xml
0071_001_as01.xml
0485_001_te01.xml
0485_001_te02.xml
0485_001_teh03.xml
```

It outputs nothing.

I only want `teh01` to `te03.xml` but not the rest. I am not sure what's wrong with my patter. Can someone help me about it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Your pattern seems to be mismatch to begin with. the letter "te" and the 2 digits - how it will match ?

Comment: @Adidi Ha, you are correct. Got it now! Thanks!~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob` doesn't support `[0-9]{2}`, you have to write `[0-9][0-9]`:

```
foreach(glob($root . "../test/te[0-9][0-9].xml") as $filename){
  echo $filename;
}
```

for your files, you need to use:

```
foreach(glob($root . "../test/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_te[0-9][0-9].xml") as $filename){
  echo $filename;
}
```

Or you could add a regex check:

```
foreach(glob($root . "../test/*.xml") as $filename){
  if (preg_match('/_te\d{2}\.xml$/', $filename, $matches)){
     echo $filename;
  }
}
```

Comment: Turns out I didn't match the patter before the te. Thanks for the help!